# Nested deep select with scoped CSS in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

I have three Vue components: `Parent`, `Child` and `GrandChild`.
I want to access the style of the grandchild component in the scope of the parent component.

I can access the style of the child component using `::v-deep` but I can't find how to go a level deeper

To access the child component, I write:

```
//in Parent component
<style scoped>
  ::v-deep .child {
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>
```

I am new to web development, but I couldn't find the syntax, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `/deep/ .child {
        background-color: green;
     }`

Comment: @tyutyut Both `::v-deep` and the `>>>` syntax  work for me to select a child that's several levels deep. Maybe something else is going on in your project. E.g. your child selector is wrong, or something else has a higher selection precedence (!important or an id).

Comment: If you are going to use /deep/ instead of ::v-deep. Keep in mind that both sass and dart-sass do not support /deep/. Node-sass does.

Comment: @DavidWeldon "E.g. your child selector is wrong, or something else has a higher selection precedence (!important or an id)." It could also be inline styling :)